# Nginx reverse proxy multiple locations not loading

Tags: nginx, sonarqube, nginx-reverse-proxy

On my `CentOS-7.6` I have two SonarQube Web application running with different ports.

```
$SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties file updated like below.

For Application:1
sonar.web.context=/application 
sonar.web.port=9090

For Application:2 
sonar.web.context=/application-old
sonar.web.port=9089
```

For reverse proxy I have installed `nginx version: nginx/1.12.2`.

To run both the application on 80 port with single IP address my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/application.conf` file has the below code.

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 65.66.67.68;

        location /application {
            proxy_pass http://65.66.67.68:9090;
        }

        location /application-old {
            proxy_pass http://65.66.67.68:9089;
        }
}
```

Here problem is while accessing below through 80 port.

```
1) http://65.66.67.68/application 
2) http://65.66.67.68/application-old
```

The application which is running on `port – 9090` showing `page loading` on IE, Chrome & firefox browsers. Screenshot as follows.

[image]

whereas along with port - `http://65.66.67.68:9090/application` it is working.

And the other location application`(http://65.66.67.68/application-old)` is loading and working.

My application runs with two different location below are them.

```
1) http://65.66.67.68:9090/application 
2) http://65.66.67.68:9089/application-old
```

So how to run both applications in 80 port and with single IP address.

Comment: How should nginx know if a user wants to visit website 1 or website 2? The locations to both sites is the same

Comment: updated in question section.

Comment: Did you try: `http://65.66.67.68/application`?

Comment: yes http://65.66.67.68/application --> Not working and http://65.66.67.68/application-old --> working.

Comment: check log directory and add log trace for 65.66.67.68/application (comment sensible parts)

Answer (score 0):

You should define your reverse proxy with [proxy_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) and apply them everytime when you change configuration file.

```
location /application/ {
    proxy_pass http://65.66.67.68:9090;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host;
    #proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    #proxy_send_timeout 3600;
    #proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    #send_timeout 3600;
}

location /application-old/ {
    proxy_pass http://65.66.67.68:9089;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host;
    #proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    #proxy_send_timeout 3600;
    #proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    #send_timeout 3600;
}
```

Then:

```
$ nginx -t (test if syntax is OK)
$ nginx -s reload (apply new changes)
```

Now, access your application from web browser

```
http://65.66.67.68/aplication
http://65.66.67.68/aplication-old
```

In `logs` directory, you can check any error / info messages.

**Update:** Make sure nginx loaded correctly. Sometimes, it gets buggy and doesn't update correctly. Restart/kill nginx and start again

Comment: I have added proxy_set_header Host 65.66.67.68:9090; and proxy_set_header Host 65.66.67.68:9089; proxy_header under location category. nginx –t finished syntax is ok and nginx -s reload no error and even in /var/log/nginx/error.log also no error. But still same problem. Can update the required in answer section. It will save my life I am new to nginx.

Comment: Can you post log messages (info) for `http://65.66.67.68/aplication` ? Your app (http://65.66.67.68:9090/application) needs to send requests always under `/application` (context path) and never `/` (root). Make sure

Comment: log has 2019/08/30 17:13:21 [notice] 7120#0: signal process started.

Comment: Even chrome browser console log also not showing anything.

Comment: Let's continue here [https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198727/nginx-reverse-proxy](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198727/nginx-reverse-proxy)

Comment: Still same problem.(The SonarQube which is running on 9090) port sometime works on browser and sometime it continuously says loading. I have upgraded Nginx to latest version - 1.17.3 and still same problem. Do I need to install any module to get it work properly?

Comment: It looks Nginx unable to handle both the applications on 80 port. Bcoz in my/etc/nginx/conf.d/application.conf with single application it is able to handle, the moment I included another location block in my nginx application.conf file one application started showing loading in browser.

Comment: Nginx access.log and error.log both doesn't show any errors. Can someone assist. Would be great helpful.

Comment: Firewall disabled, Nginx folder permission verified looks no problem, still on firefox, Chrome & IE it shows "Loading" any clue or suggestions to fix would help me a lot.

Comment: Enabled debug mode in error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug; here also no error message.

Comment: nginx is running but not serving in browser for one application.